# How do I call a double from another class?

Tags: java, class, variables, double

I am creating a calculator with a gui that returns weekly pay with a tip rate included as practice and ran into a problem.

```
        public class NetPay {

        public static double netPayRate(double hourlyPayRate, double tipRate){
        double netPayRate=(hourlyPayRate*tipRate)+hourlyPayRate;

        return netPayRate*40;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

I was wondering how I could call hourlyPayRate and tipRate in the gui class I have made?

Thank you!

gui:

```
public class DiffGui {

NetPay netPayRate= new NetPay();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    new DiffGui();
}


public DiffGui(){
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable(){

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try{
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());

        }catch(ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();

        }
        //the frame everything is built on
        JFrame mainFrame= new JFrame("Testing");
            mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            mainFrame.add(new Test());
            mainFrame.pack();
            mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            mainFrame.setVisible(true);

        //code for the textboxes+button & panel below
            JPanel southPanel= new JPanel();
            JTextField salary= new JTextField();
            JTextField tips= new JTextField();
                    southPanel.add(salary);
                    southPanel.add(tips);
            JButton calculateButton= new JButton("Calculate!");
                    southPanel.add(calculateButton);
                    mainFrame.getContentPane().add(southPanel , BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                    calculateButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
// calculate button action listener
                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {




                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }

                    });

        }


    });
}
public class Test extends JPanel{
public Test(){
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    BackgroundPane backPane= new BackgroundPane();
    backPane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    add(backPane);


     try {
         BufferedImage tryCatch = ImageIO.read(new File("pictures/background.gif"));
         backPane.setbackgroundImage(tryCatch);
     } catch (IOException ex) {
         ex.printStackTrace();


     }
     JLabel viewing= new JLabel("Pay Calculator");
     viewing.setOpaque(true);
     viewing.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
     viewing.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
     viewing.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(25,25,25,25));
     backPane.add(viewing);
}
public class BackgroundPane extends JPanel{
    private BufferedImage image;
        @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
                BufferedImage image = getBackgroundImage();
                Dimension size= super.getPreferredSize();
                    if(image != null){
                        size.width = Math.max(size.width, image.getWidth());
                        size.height = Math.max(size.height, image.getHeight());
                    }
                    return size;

    }
        public BufferedImage getBackgroundImage(){
            return image;
        }
        public void setbackgroundImage(BufferedImage x){
            if( image!=x){
                BufferedImage prevous= image;
                image=x;
                firePropertyChange("background" , prevous , image);
                revalidate();
                repaint();

            }
        }
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics graphs){
            super.paintComponent(graphs);
            BufferedImage backpane= getBackgroundImage();
            if(backpane != null){
                int x = (getWidth()-backpane.getWidth())/2;
                int y = (getHeight()-backpane.getHeight())/2;
                graphs.drawImage(backpane,x,y,this);

            }


        }
}

}
}
```

The calculate button action listener, specifically on the variables salary and tips are where I would like to insert values in my gui and then have the pay calculator use those values to find the weekly pay

Comment: declare both value in main method and  pass to `netPayRate`.

Comment: I can't understand question properly? Is the function you want to call is a public method you want to use in another class?

Comment: Do not call any methods from the gui class directly, instead store those values in a model class...

Comment: I want to call hourlyPayRate and tipRate in another class so that I can assign them to JTextFields in public methods so that when the user inputs his hourly rate and the tip rate and clicks the JButton it runs the above program using the values inputted.

Comment: Gui code is now inserted

Comment: In DiffGUI, where you call NetPay? When button clicked?

Comment: yes when the button is clicked

Comment: You can't call a double.

Comment: @shmosel - I have assumed from the code the question is actually to get the value returned from the function netPayRate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to pass the value from DiffGUI to PayNet. You can write this in your button click

```
calculateButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    // calculate button action listener
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               double salaryValue = Double.valueOf(salary.getText()); // get value from JTextField
               double tipsValue = Double.valueOf(tips.getText());
               NetPay net = new NetPay();
               double netpayValue = net.netPayRate(salaryValue, tipsValue);

            }
        });
```

Comment: yes thank you! Once I pass it though how would I go about making the netPayrate*40 from the NetPay class display in the gui?

Comment: `SomeJTextField.setText(Double.toString( netpayValue));`

Answer (score 0):

I have assumed you wanted netpay as that seems most logical from the code and caculate button. If so, you just need to call the method from the class NetPay, pass the parameter and put the return value into the correct place in the GUI. So, assuming salary is hourlyrate and that you cast salary and tips to doubles then the code would be somthing like:

```
NetPay netPayRate= new NetPay();

double netpay= netPayRate(salary, tips);
```

Then put netpay cast as string into correct object on gui. Assuming salary is the variable for houlyrate, I would consider renaming it, as salary tends to denote the annual amount. Similarly, tips would suggest the value rather than the rate, so worth renaming.